# How to get the current record auto incremented field value after inserted in Angular2+ ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, angular, typescript

I have a problem.I want to get the last inserted row auto increment field value.When inserting I'm not pass that value.It will auto generated value.
First I add data to the table,add call back to get the all data from that table.If not using call back I can't get the current row data.
Here is the way I used,

```
 blockBusinessPartnerItem(): void {
    this.isBusinessPartnerSelected = false;
    this.logger.debug('Now in blockBusinessPartnerItem method');
    const businessPartnerItem = {
      BlockKey: 0,
      BpKey: this.businessPartnerId,
      ItemKey: Number(this.itemKey)
    };

    this.adminService.addBusinessPartnerItemBlock(businessPartnerItem).subscribe(response => {
      this.toasterService.popAsync('success', 'Successfully Added Business Partner Item');
    }, error => {
      const message = 'Unable to submit business partner item';
      this.toasterService.popAsync('error', message);
    }, () => {
      this.adminService.getBusinessPartnerItemBlock().subscribe((data) => {

const arrSize = data.length;
const siz = arrSize - 1;
const row = data[arrSize - 1] ;
this.logger.debug('current block key :' + this.currentBlockKey);


      this.params.api.addItems([{blockKey: data[arrSize - 1].BlockKey , bpKey: this.businessPartnerId ,
         bpName: this.businessPartnerName, itemKey: this.itemKey}]);


      });

      // this.businessPartnerId = 0;
      // this.itemKey = '';
      }
      );







  }
```

problem is when debug it blockKey is show as undefined.

```
this.params.api.addItems([{blockKey: data[arrSize - 1].BlockKey , bpKey: this.businessPartnerId ,
             bpName: this.businessPartnerName, itemKey: this.itemKey}]);
```

Comment: What does your console show? Which field is undefined?

Comment: when debugging blockKey field show as undefined

Comment: What is adminService.getBusinessPartnerItemBlock() returning?

Comment: It returns an array

Comment: export interface IBusinesPartnerItemBlackListItem {
    BlockKey: number;
    BpKey: number;
    BpName: string;
    ItemKey: number;

}
this is the return type

Comment: Can anyone please tell me if you know this,
 this.adminService.getBusinessPartnerItemBlock().subscribe((data) => { }
in this case data contains the getBusinessPartnerItemBlock() method return array.
how to get it's values?
I used
const rowData :data[arrSize - 1].BlockKey;

but it shows rowData is undefined.how to solve this?

Comment: Can you actually provide a sample of the data it returns? If it's undefined then that means there's no data in that field.

Comment: here is the screenshot when debugging
https://i.imgur.com/xNWY5WU.png

it contains the array data

Comment: array data start with simple letters like bpKey, bpName. but when getting I can't put simple letters,it means

const row :data.pop() this will return the last row.
it contains data {bpKey:222,bpName:'aaa' ..........}
wen try to get row specific collumn data 
row.BpName can use but row.bpName can't. actual return type properties in capital letters.but in debug mode those are show in simple letters

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is caused because you're accessing `data[arrSize - 1].BlockKey` instead of `data[arrSize - 1].blockKey`. Note the difference in case (b versus B).

JavaScript is a case-sensitive language. BlockKey is a different variable (which doesn't exist in your return data) to blockKey (which does exist in your return data).

Have a look at this article for more information:
https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/javascript-the-definitive/0596000480/ch02s02.html

Comment: if I put data[arrSize - 1].blockKey ,then it show an error. blockKey cannot find.
I fixed this problem in this way
I got the last inserted row like this
const row = data.pop();
cons blockKey = row['blockKey'];

anyway thank you very much your help..